Is it possible to arrange the free n-minoes of orders 2, 3, 4 and 5 into a rectangle?
To be explicit, the shapes pictured below, with reflections permitted.

Can these be packed into a rectangle?
This puzzle arose from discussion on r/mathmemes. No solution was posted (and I don't know the solution, either).
Some preliminary analysis:

Adding the single square makes this impossible. The total area of the pictured shapes is 88, so adding one gives a prime number.
There are no parity concerns, as the grid will require even parity (either 4x22 or 8x11) and the sum of piece parity is also even.


There are no parity concerns whatever parity your selected grid requires, because there are odd-sized pieces involved, any one of which can be used to adjust parity.

The answer is

 

Apologies for reusing OP's colour scheme. The big violet blob consists of the Z pentomino and the T tetris piece.

One solution out of many

Here's a solution to the 4x22. It's made up of a 4x(2,3,4,6,7). 4x(1,2,3,4,5,7) and 4x(1,2,3,4,6,6) are both impossible.

 


The subrectangles also cleanly rearrange into a large number of 8×11 solutions.

A simpler method to see that 4x22 is possible:

 First, it is known that there are many ways to pack 12 pentominoes into 4x15.


 Then it suffices to show that we can pack 5 tetrominoes, 2 trominoes and 1 domino into 4x7.


 While we cannot pack 5 tetrominoes into 4x5 (parity problem with T), there are many ways to pack 4x7 with the help of smaller pieces, including but not limited to:
TTTIIII
LTrr..i
LSSrOOi
LLSSOOi

OOiiiT.
OOSSTT.
LLLSSTr
LIIIIrr

ILL..OO
ILiiiOO
ILTSSrr
ITTTSSr

